# mod_rewrite without creating subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

i'm trying to get my rewrite rules working, so that /stream/file.mp4 redirects to /stream.php?f=file.mp4.
However this only works when i create a folder named stream. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^stream/(.*)$ /stream.php?f=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in root .htaccess with `MultiViews` disabled:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^stream/(.+)$ stream.php?f=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
```